# Popup Image Gallery using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a website that contains a gallery. I have made my code in HTML and CSS to customize the shape of my gallery within the page. I would like to make a popup for every image within the gallery once clicked!
 My knowledge in Jquery is very basic, so any kind of help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="showcase">
    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="Gallery/Pic1.jpg"><img 
    src="Thumb/Pic1.jpg" alt="" height="240" width="190"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery/Pic2.jpg"><img src="Thumb/Pic2.jpg" 
             alt="" height="240" width="190"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery/Pic3.jpg"><img src="Thumb/Pic3.jpg"   
             alt="" height="240" width="190"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery/Pic4.jpg"><img src="Thumb/Pic4.jpg"  
             alt="" height="240" width="190"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery/Pic5.jpg"><img src="Thumb/Pic5.jpg"  
             alt="" height="240" width="190"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Style Sheet :

```css
.showcase
{
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.showcase ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

.showcase ul li
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 25px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px #ffffff, 0px 2px 4px 2px rgba(98, 67, 36,   
    0.5);
}

.showcase ul li.current
{
    margin-left: 0;``
}

.showcase ul li a
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please look around at some options for [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com) that can do this for you. First try those, if they don't work, or you don't like them, try writing your own code. And if that code doesn't work, then come here with the problem.

Comment: I have an issue with the script as I already used this script with my slider in the main page <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>. Therefore adding another script for the gallery would conflict ! Any ideas of what to do ?

Comment: What script? You show only HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining. I already have a slider image in my website using JQuery script for it to work. Besides I want to do a gallery based on JQuery too. Can I use the same script in my header i.e. <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> ?

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery has helped me in the past

[Simple Modal Popup Window](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Super-Simple-Modal-Popups-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions.html)

Instructions are pretty simple.You might have to add a unique identifier for each item though. The sample Jquery is set up to call one . You would need to modify it to dynamically update per image.